# 2D/3D Визуализация DICOM

Tags: c#, изображения, визуализация, dicom

Работаю над приложением, одной из задачей которого является визуализация изображения, хранящегося в **DICOM**-файле.

Как, собственно, происходит визуализация этого файла? Какие данные нужно распарсить из этого файла и какие преобразования с ними делать, чтобы получить на выходе изображение? Я знаю, что оно может быть как серией разных снимков, так и просто единичным двумерным изображением. В интернете, пока что, не нашёл ответа на свой вопрос и прошу помощи в поиске данной информации.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Исправьте ваш вопрос, чтобы он был сфокусирован на одной теме, чтобы можно было дать адекватный ответ. Если у вас несколько тем, создайте несколько вопросов. Для понимания обратитесь в [Какие вопросы лучше не задавать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @Dmitry поправил

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю самого механизма визуализации, однако я нашёл несколько полезных репозиториев на гитхабе, которые умеют визуализировать DICOM:

- [fo-dicom/fo-dicom](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom)
- [zhaotianff/ImageViewer](https://github.com/zhaotianff/ImageViewer)

Также есть платные инструменты для преобразования DICOM в другие типы изображений и, возможно, рендера

- [Aspose.Imaging](https://products.aspose.com/imaging/net/) ([статья про Aspose.Imaging и DICOM](https://blog.aspose.com/2020/04/01/convert-dicom-to-jpeg-gif-png-bmp-images-in-csharp-net/))

Comment: инструмент то я использую fo-dicom, но чтобы визуализировать мне нужна информация - как это сделать. Именно в этом вопрос, т.к.  Примеров или статей я пока не нашёл

Comment: @0_o для 2D визуализации в библиотеке fo-dicom есть метод превращающий DICOM в Bitmap

Comment: https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/blob/development/Documentation/v5/usage/image_rendering.md